# Derivative of a Portfolio (return)

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Given that $S(t)$ is an asset denominated in a foreign currency, and $X(t)$ is the current domestic/foreign exchange rate. Could somebody tell me why the Return $\frac{dP}{P}$ is given by $\frac{dP}{P} = \frac{dS_t}{S_t} +\frac{dX_t}{X_t}+ \frac{dS_t}{S_t} \cdot \frac{dX_t}{X_t}$. I think the value of the Porfolio is given by $P_t = S_t \cdot X_t$. Intuitively I think I understand the derivative/return, but how do I get there mathematically? Where does $\frac{dS_t}{S_t} \cdot \frac{dX_t}{X_t}$ mathematically come from?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well....it's not clear (to me) why we'd keep one second order term but ignore the others.    Still, use $F(t+\Delta t)=F(t)+\Delta F$ to first order for each of $P,S,X$ and then divide the resulting equation by $P=SX$.  As I say, this keeps exactly one of the three second terms so a decision has been made to disregard second derivatives.

Comment: Are you intending on using Itô calculus here?

Comment: Thank you @lulu! I quickly googled what that is @Nap D. Lover, I think that is what's been done here. Would make sense in this context  if I understand it correctly

Comment: @lulu, could you perhaps tell me how one generraly get's the 2nd order term in this case by taking the derivative?

Comment: I wrote it out.  Writing $P(t+\Delta t)=S(t+\Delta t)X(t+\Delta t)$ then using the linear approximation for each term we get $P'(t)\Delta t \approx S(t)X'(t)\Delta t + X(t)S'(t)\Delta t + S'(t)X'(t)(\Delta t)^2$.  Now divide both sides by $P=SX$ and write, e.g., $dP=P'(t)\Delta t$.